# How to minify java script files in a rails application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to reduce the load time of my rails application on the production server. For now, my concern is only to reduce the assets loading time and not changing the business logic. An online tester identified I have 2.25 MB of JS files which include third party jquery plugins. And currently, all my assets are rendering from **app/assets** path. The console loads files like this on the index page:

`Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.self` Like this, there are a number of js files.

In my **production.rb** file I have set

> config.serve_static_files = true
>   config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

In my **nginx.conf** I am serving assets as follows

```
location ^~ /(assets|fonts|swfs|images)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js ^[^_]*.css *.css.erb )

  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  #config.serve_static_assets = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  #config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] 

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV["SMTP_HOST"] }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = ENV["SMTP_HOST"]
  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    #Enter the smtp provider here ex: smtp.mandrillapp.com
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    port: ENV['SMTP_PORT'].to_i,
    #Enter the smtp domain here ex: vendaxo.com
    domain: ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"],
    #Enter the user name for smtp provider here
    user_name: ENV["SMTP_USERNAME"],
    #Enter the password for smtp provider here
    password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Capistrano **deploy.rb** posting assets lines only as requested.

```
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads", "public/assets"
namespace :deploy do
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
end
```

What should I do in order to reduce this assets load time? Let me know if any further information needed.

Comment: Do you use a reverse-proxy server like nginx or apache?

Comment: gzip those....!

Comment: Yes. There I am already serving assets. I will add that in question.

Comment: Post the whole content for `production.rb`

Comment: I did gzip them @Jai

Comment: Added `production.rb` file  @Зелёный

Comment: All looks good, do you use `assets:precompile`? How you're deploying your server?

Comment: I am using `capistrano` to deploy it to server. I have edited question with lines concerning assets on **deploy.rb**. Please check. When I checked on server the assets are in this path **shared/public/assets**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

and push all compressed js/css files. It will save your load time and compress all js/css/images.

Comment: After this should I change the mapping path in `application.rb` ?

Comment: No. Nothing to change in application.rb

Comment: Okay. I am not entirely clear about this assets thing. One thing I wanna ask, if you could help me clear this. Now I have assets in two paths `app/assets` and  also in `public/assets` so now which assets will be loaded when the application is running?

Comment: on precompile all js/css/images under app/assets are compressed in public/assets folder and when you run application assets are loaded from /public folder.

Comment: whenever you have done any changes in js or css file under /app/assets, you have to again run rake assets:precompile and push the files.

Comment: I haven't pushed it to production yet. But it did compress js files. I ll accept it. But how can I cross check where it is loading assets from?

Comment: Its loaded from public/assets, right click on browser -> Inspect element -> source -> check js files path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142244/discussion-between-user3576036-and-puneet18).